# jQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, custom-attributes

I am trying to get an array of checkboxes that ARE checked AND have a certain attribute (tag) that is NOT blank.

(I know that the attribute called `tag` is not HTML compliant but it does work across the major browsers and makes life alot simpler!)

e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="First" tag="first@whatever.com" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="Second" tag="" checked="checked">
```

In the above example, only the first one should be in the array
The code I have started with is:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked')
```

But that obviously doesnt ensure that the `tag` attribute is not blank

**UPDATE**
Sorry, something I didnt think of before - I also need to get a list of the checkboxes whose `tag` is blank so the user can be warned. The following dont work:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked[title=""]')
$('input:checkbox:checked:not([title])')
```

Thanks for all the responses, much appreciated!

**UPDATE 2**

The above code (using `title` to store the additional data) doesnt work purely it seems because of the title atribute! When I changed it to `tag` it worked perfectly.

Comment: Why not use `alt`, which is HTML compliant?

Comment: @Robert: because *alt* has a defined function in the browser. *Alt* is about the appearance.

Comment: Consider using `data-tag` instead of `tag`, ala: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data

Comment: @Georg `alt` is meant as a short description for user agents that can't display forms/images etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input:checkbox[tag!='']:checked")
```

Answer (score 3):

attributes use the [tag="first@whatever.com"] syntax in JQuery; try appending that as in:

```
$('input:checkbox[tag="first@whatever.com"]:checked')
```

The other option is you may want to check out the data method in JQuery, which can append data to an HTML element, instead of using the tag attribute: http://docs.jquery.com/Data

Answer (score 3):

HTML compliant

HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' alt='bleh' checked='checked' id='1' />
<input type='checkbox' alt='' checked='checked' id='2' />
```

And Selector:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked[alt!=""]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LVqLw/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `[tag]` to test if it is blank or if the tag exists at all.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xCFfa/

```
$(":checkbox:checked[tag]");
```